# How can I remove B -> A from a list if A -> B is in the list?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a list of transformations like this:

```
list = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "D"}
```

As this is used to plot an undirected graph with `GraphPlot`, I don't want to have an Edge between the vertices A-B *and* B-A. I just want one of them.

How do I remove either `A -> B` or `B -> A` from this list? In the end, I want the list to look like this:

```
{"A" -> "B", "C" -> "D"}
```

I've tried using `DeleteDuplicates`, but I don't think I understand the testing part of that function (I should add that I'm a Mathematica beginner ... )

I made a function that can compare two transformations:

```
CmpTrans[x_,y_] := (x[[1]]/.x) == y[[1]]
```

It returns `True` for `CmpTrans[A->B, B->A]`, but I can't seem to use this is the testing part of `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider `MultiedgeStyle-> None`?  For example: `GraphPlot[list, VertexLabeling -> True, MultiedgeStyle -> None]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
rules = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "D"};

Rule @@@ Union[Composition[Sort, List] @@@ rules]
(* {"A" -> "B", "C" -> "D"} *)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! That works perfectly. I'm not sure I really understand how it works, but figuring that out is good practice for me.

Comment: It's not too hard; I temporarily turn all your `Rule[]`s to `List[]`s with `Apply[]` (that is, `@@@`), sort those `List[]`s, delete duplicates with `Union[]`, and then change the `List[]`s back to `Rule[]`s.

Comment: It's seem `Union[Sort /@ rules]` work,too.

Answer (score 25):

If you do not mind changing your edge directions and order, as J.M.'s answer does, this can be done much more simply since [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) works on arbitrary expressions:

```
Union[Sort /@ rules]
```

If you do not want to change the directions or order, you can use this:

```
First /@ GatherBy[rules, Sort]
```

*Mathematica 10* introduced [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html) which may also be used:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Sort]
```

> ```
> {"A" -> "B", "C" -> "D"}
> ```

Comment: "...do not mind changing your edge directions..." - as he wants to draw an undirected graph, he certainly doesn't.

Comment: @J.M. I actually did notice that, but I thought it best to include that anyway.  Questions do change themselves sometimes. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Using Mathematica 7

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
Rule @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ EdgeList[list]]
```

giving

> {"A" -> "B", "C" -> "D"}

Answer (score 10):

Note that `CmpTrans` that you wrote isn't the correct test. Here's an example where it gives the wrong result:

```
CmpTrans["A" -> "B", "B" -> "C"]

(*
==> True
*)
```

Once we fix that, maybe with something like:

```
CmpTrans[x_, y_] := x === Reverse[y]

CmpTrans["A" -> "B", "B" -> "C"]

(*
==> False
*)

CmpTrans["A" -> "B", "B" -> "A"]

(*
==> True
*)
```

then we can simply use `CmpTrans` as the second argument to `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
list = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "D"};

DeleteDuplicates[list, CmpTrans]

(*
==> {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "D"}
*)
```

Comment: One possibly problematic thing about this method is that `DeleteDuplicates` with explicit comparison function will switch to the quadratic-time pairwise-comparison-based algorithm, making this impractical even for moderately sized graphs. For example: `DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@Outer[Rule, Range[50], Range[50]], CmpTrans] ` takes about 5 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for the corrected function. Embarrassingly I didn't test my version with a False case.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `UndirectedGraph` directly for your graph problem

```
list = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "D"};

Graph[list, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
g = UndirectedGraph[Graph[list], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
EdgeList[g]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** For  versions 10+ there is `DeleteDuplicatesBy`:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort] @ list
```

> `{"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "D"}`

**Original post:**

You can also use an `Orderless` function `foo`.

> In matching patterns with Orderless functions, all possible orders of arguments are tried.

```
list = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "D"};

SetAttributes[foo, Orderless];

Rule @@@ DeleteDuplicates[foo @@@ list]   
(* or  DeleteDuplicates[bar @@@ list] /. bar-> Rule *)
(* or DeleteDuplicates[list /. Rule -> bar] /. bar -> Rule *)
```

> `{"A" -> "B","C" -> "D"}`

Comment: I don't think TransitiveReductionGraph does what the OP has asked (unless I misunderstood something).

Comment: @Szabolcs, deleted that part.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using pure pattern matching

```
{"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "D"}
/. {before___, a_ -> b_, between___, b_ -> a_, after___} 
:> {before, a -> b, between, after}
```

which leaves the list in its original order.

If there are multiple duplicate entries one can use `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) instead of `ReplaceAll`(`/.`) to sweep the list until all duplicates are cleared

```
{"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "D", "B" -> "A"} 
//. {before___, a_ -> b_, between___, b_ -> a_, after___}
:> {before, a -> b, between, after}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another proposal. Short but probably not very efficient.

```
list = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "C" -> "D"}
DeleteDuplicates[list,  Function[{x, y} , x == Reverse[y]]]
```