# How to sort Table/Matrix including legend(Labellings)

Tags: functions, matrix, list-manipulation, sorting

I want to sort table including its legend  for graph

I have table similar to

```
M1   M2   M3 
1     5    2
3     1    4 
4     2   -10
5     7    11
6    -2    1
```

I want the labellings `M1`, `M2` and  `M3` to move with the first row of numbers while sorting by row basis.

```
    M1   M3   M2 
    1     2    5
    ...........
     ...........
```

OK The code is below

```
(* Initial matrix *)
h = {{M1, M2, M3}, {1, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, -10}, {7, 5, 11}, {6, -2, 1}}
```

then sorting by basis `h1 = Sort /@ h` gives

```
 M1,   M2,  M3
 1,    2,  5
 1,    3,  4
 -10,  2,  4
 5,    7,  11
 -2,   1,  6
```

I want `M1`, `M2` and `M3` to be together with the fist row of numerical values since they are labellings attached to the first numerical values of each column

AS

```
M1   M3   M2 
1     2    5
```

.....
....

In that way it will be easy to put the legend in graphs

Comment: Please post a code example for the list definition

Answer (score 2):

```
t = {{"M1", "M2", "M3"}, {1, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 4}}
Join[{t[[1, Ordering[t[[2]]]]]}, Sort /@ t[[2 ;;]]] // TableForm
(*
    M1  M3  M2
    1   2   5
    1   3   4
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  belisarius already showed what is perhaps the best, using `Ordering`.  Another is a decorate-and-sort.  In steps:

```
h = {{M1, M2, M3}, {1, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, -10}, {7, 5, 11}, {6, -2, 1}};

{Thread[#2 -> #], ##2} & @@ h

Sort /@ %

{Last /@ #, ##2} & @@ %
```

> ```
> {{1 -> M1, 5 -> M2, 2 -> M3}, {1, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 4}, {4, 2, -10}, {7, 5, 11}, {6, -2, 1}}
>
> {{1 -> M1, 2 -> M3, 5 -> M2}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, {-10, 2, 4}, {5, 7, 11}, {-2, 1, 6}}
>
> {{M1, M3, M2}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, {-10, 2, 4}, {5, 7, 11}, {-2, 1, 6}}
> ```

As one line:

```
{Last /@ #, ##2} & @@ Sort /@ {Thread[#2 -> #], ##2} & @@ h
```

In the code above I used `Rule` (short form `->`) arbitrarily; `Sort` works on other heads as well as `List`.

`Ordering` is more concise however, e.g. either of these:

```
Join[{#[[Ordering@#2]]}, Sort /@ {##2}] & @@ h   (* belisarius's code refactored *)

MapThread[Part, {h, {#2, ##2} & @@ Ordering /@ h}]
```