# How to exchange two arguments?

Tags: pure-function

Recently, I have being using *Mathematica* to write my undergraduate paper. I want to use two pattern lists such as `{ A -> a, B -> b, c -> C, ....}` and `{ a -> A, b -> B, c -> C, ....}` to make my code short. I can exchange `{ A -> a, B -> b, c -> C, ....}`'s elements to achieve `{ a -> A, b -> B, c -> C, ....}`, my trail is as below:

```
firstPattern = { A -> a, B -> b, c -> C, one -> two, tom -> david};
```

To achieve `{ a -> A, b -> B, C -> c, two -> one, david -> tom}`, I write the code:

```
{#1, #2} -> {#2, #1}& /@ firstPattern
```

However, it failed. I wonder why and how to correct it.

Comment: Is this what you intend? `{#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> {#[[2]], #[[1]]} & /@ firstPattern`

Comment: @bills,+1,OK,thanks sincerely,I achieve the right result

Comment: It doesn't get simpler than `Reverse /@ firstPattern` :)

Comment: Somewhat related: [(1302)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because life is more fun with infix:

```
firstPattern ~Reverse~ 2
```

> ```
> {a -> A, b -> B, C -> c, two -> one, david -> tom}
> ```

(The serious point of this answer is that you can use the second parameter of [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reverse.html) to determine exactly what levels of the expression you wish to reverse.)

Also quite direct and terse:

```
#2 -> # & @@@ firstPattern
```

> ```
> {a -> A, b -> B, C -> c, two -> one, david -> tom}
> ```

This works where your attempt doesn't by using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) at level one, which has the shorthand `@@@`.  This lets you access the parts of the rules rather than the entire rules themselves.

---

#### Timings

Timings, conducted in version 7, for various methods posted so far.

```
timeAvg = 
  Function[func,
    Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}],
    HoldFirst];

rules = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[999, {500000, 2}];

Reverse /@ rules     // timeAvg
Reverse[rules, 2]    // timeAvg
#2 -> # & @@@ rules  // timeAvg
rules[[All, {2, 1}]] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.1934
>
> 0.1342
>
> 0.259
>
> 0.1902
> ```

---

In an attempt to make this answer more worthy of the Accept I'd like to arbitrarily address an edge case that might come up.  Suppose you have [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) expressions and you wish to reverse them:

```
rules = {a :> 1 + 1, b :> 2 + 2, c :> 3 + 3};
rules ~Reverse~ 2
```

> ```
> {2 :> a, 4 :> b, 6 :> c}
> ```

Note that e.g. `1 + 1` became `2`; for the sake of the illustration let's consider this unacceptable.  Then we would need to wrap the left-hand-side in [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldPattern.html).  A direct attempt using `@@@` fails because the anonymous [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) does not hold its arguments (by default):

```
HoldPattern[#2] -> # & @@@ rules
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[2] -> a, HoldPattern[4] -> b, HoldPattern[6] -> c}
> ```

One could add a [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) Attribute to the function but usually replacement patterns are simpler:

```
Replace[rules, (L_ :> R_) :> (HoldPattern[R] :> L), 1]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[1 + 1] :> a, HoldPattern[2 + 2] :> b, HoldPattern[3 + 3] :> c}
> ```

Such rules may seem pointless but they *can* be useful for manipulating held expressions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard.Perfect!

Answer (score 6):

I always go with `Part` before attempting anything else:

```
firstPattern[[All, {2, 1}]]
```

To me at least it seems far simpler and more intuitive than many other approaches.

Comment: Great!  For anyone wondering how/why this works see: [Head and everything except Head?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121)

Comment: Very neat! Never thought about this one!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't get simpler than

```
Reverse /@ firstPattern
```

While `Reverse` is often used only on lists, it acts with any head, so `Reverse@Rule[a, b]` is `Rule[b, a]`.