# Delete redundant {x,y} pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

Working through the problems from Hazrat's Mathematica book and there's a simple exercise to find all the square numbers where $n^2+m^2=h^2$ yields $h$ as an integer (I think they're also called Pythagorean triples?) for $n$ and $m$ 1-100.

Anyway, I'm still learning so I did a brute force attack on every `{n,m}` pair:

```
squareNumberQ[{n_Integer,m_Integer}]:= IntegerQ[Sqrt[n^2+m^2]] ;
allPossiblePairs = Flatten[Table[{n,m},{n,1,10},{m,1,10}],1] ;
squareNumbers = Select[allPossiblePairs, squareNumberQ]
(* {{3,4},{4,3},{6,8},{8,6}} *)
```

I understand I could wrap all that into one line but I'm at the stage where I'm still wrestling with `#&` syntax so doing it piece by piece helps me debug the individual steps.

My question is how do I delete one of the pairs as `{3,4}` is the same as `{4,3}` for this exercise.  I can do it by changing the `Table` command and re-running:

```
Flatten[Table[{n,m},{n,1,10},{m,n,10}],1]
```

and there are already a few comments on alternate ways to eliminate duplicates from the candidate `{x,y}` pairs but I'm wondering how you would delete them if this wasn't an option.

There *should* be a way to `DeleteCases` based on a pattern `{x_,y_} == {y_,x_}` in the results? but my attempt is failing miserably ie:

```
DeleteCases[squareNumbers,#1[[_,1]]==#2[[_,2]]&]
```

I've hunted for variations of 'delete duplicate pairs' but most DeleteCases examples I've found are simple T/F statements on a single element of the list.

Trivial example but I'm still wrapping my head around this pattern matching business.

Comment: May be like this: `Union[allPossiblePairs,
 SameTest -> (#1 == Reverse[#2] &)]`

Comment: before that, make the table `{n,2,10},{m,1,n-1}`

Comment: @AnjanKumar I think you need "or" `#1==#2` .  Or you could do `Sort@#1 ==Sort@#2 `

Comment: Oops - sorry I was unclear in my question although I've learned a bit already.  I was wondering how to delete duplicate pairs _after_ I've already generated them. It just seems like it should be straightforward.  I will amend original question.

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: closely related: [**1302**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/5478)

Comment: Better yet... ParallelTable[ ... ,{m,100},{n,m,1000}] - Voila! No need to delete anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort][squareNumbers]
DeleteDuplicatesBy[ReverseSort][squareNumbers] (* thanks: @Sascha *)
DeleteDuplicatesBy[squareNumbers, Sort]
DeleteCases[squareNumbers, {x_, y_} /; x > y]
DeleteCases[squareNumbers, _?(Not[OrderedQ@#] &)]
Select[squareNumbers, OrderedQ]
Select[allPossiblePairs, OrderedQ @ # && squareNumberQ @ # &]
Cases[allPossiblePairs, _?(OrderedQ@# && squareNumberQ@# &)]
Cases[allPossiblePairs, x : {_, _} /; OrderedQ@x && squareNumberQ@x]
```

all give

> {{3, 4}, {6, 8}}

Comment: You forgot the new (in 11.1) `DeleteDuplicatesBy[ReverseSort][squareNumbers]`

Comment: @Sascha, indeed:)

Comment: Or use LowerTriangularize or UpperTriangularize to delete half the matrix and then pick everything that's True in the table. I added an answer below with exact code.

Comment: Better yet... ParallelTable[ ... ,{m,100},{n,m,1000}] - Voila! No need to delete anything.

Answer (score 9):

You might consider not generating the extraneous pairs, rather than removing them. It only requires a very small change to your code.

```
pairs = Flatten[Table[{n, m}, {n, 1, 10}, {m, 1, n}], 1];
Select[pairs, squareNumberQ]
```

> `{{4, 3}, {8, 6}}`

Answer (score 8):

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ allPossiblePairs]
```

Comment: I'm sure this is the most efficient, computationally speaking (also spares the typing fingers since it is short).

Answer (score 5):

Using pattern matching i.e. `ReplaceAll`(`/.`), `Rule`(`->`) and `Condition`(`/;`)

```
squareNumbers /. {a_, b_} /; a > b -> Nothing
```

I read this (and any such) line of code to myself as

> **Replace** any list of two elements $(a,b)$  **where** $a$ is larger than $b$ **by** $Nothing$

Answer (score 4):

Since any `{n, n}` for integer `n` is not a Pythagorean triple, I suggest

```
allPossiblePairs = Subsets[Range[10], {2}]
```

as probably the shortest way to generate them.

Answer (score 4):

Just for something different `Pick` (and imho nice usecase for **`Order`**):

```
Pick[#, Order @@@ #, 1] & @ squareNumbers
```

PS. `Order` also would work in @Kuba's reference [case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/5478).

Answer (score 2):

Is

```
DeleteDuplicates[list,Sort@#==Sort@#2&]
```

what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

You can also feed all the conditions to `Solve` from the start:

```
sol = Solve[
  n^2 + m^2 == h^2 && 0 < n < 10 && 0 < m < 10 && h > 0 && n <= m,
    {n,m, h}, Integers]
```

> {{n -> 3, m -> 4, h -> 5}, {n -> 6, m -> 8, h -> 10}}

```
{n, m} /. sol
```

> {{3, 4}, {6, 8}}

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
{} ⋃ Sort /@ allPossiblePairs
```

Answer (score 1):

Why so much work for something that's done with 1 line of code?
You're deleting symmetric duplicates. Use LowerTriangularize (or UpperTriangularize) to delete everything above or below the diagonal, then select those indexes, where True indicates valid answer:

```
Position[LowerTriangularize@Parallelize@Array[IntegerQ@Sqrt[#1^2+#2^2]&,{1000,1000}],True]
```

1000x1000 search takes approx. 3.5 seconds on my machine.

**UPDATE:**

On the other hand... Forget LowerTriangularize... Just don't compute the lower half, and use optimization inspired by @UnchartedWorks:

```
Flatten[
  ParallelTable[If[IntegerQ@Abs@Complex[m,n],{n,m},Nothing],{m,1000},{n,m,1000}]
,1]
```

1.38 seconds for 1000x1000 search.

```
ListPlot[%,AspectRatio->1]
```

[image: ListPlot pythagorean thriples]

Comment: Position[LowerTriangularize@
      Parallelize@Array[IntegerQ@*Norm@*Complex, {10, 10}], True]

Comment: `Complex[]` head is BRILLIANT! )))) Works 10% faster than a List head, while giving the same result. I want to give your comment +100 ))

Comment: @UnchartedWorks ParallelTable to search half the table + your trick of Abs@Complex - less than half the execution time

Comment: Brilliant! It is good to hear it is so fast!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it more efficient, you can do it like this.

```
allPossiblePairs // DeleteDuplicates // Map[Sort] // DeleteDuplicates
```

In:

```
xss = RandomInteger[1000, {10^7, 2}];
AbsoluteTiming[xss // Map[Sort] // DeleteDuplicates]
AbsoluteTiming[ 
 xss // DeleteDuplicates // Map[Sort] // DeleteDuplicates]
```

Out:
[image]

Actually you don't have to delete duplicates, because you can list all of unique pairs directly.

In:

```
squareNumberQ[{n_Integer, m_Integer}] := IntegerQ[Sqrt[n^2 + m^2]];
allPossiblePairs = Flatten[Table[{n, m}, {n, 1, 10}, {m, 1, n}], 1]
squareNumbers = Select[allPossiblePairs, squareNumberQ]
```

Out:

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 
  3}, {4, 4}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 1}, {6, 
  2}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 
  4}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 1}, {8, 2}, {8, 3}, {8, 4}, {8, 
  5}, {8, 6}, {8, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 3}, {9, 4}, {9, 
  5}, {9, 6}, {9, 7}, {9, 8}, {9, 9}, {10, 1}, {10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 
  4}, {10, 5}, {10, 6}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}, {10, 9}, {10, 10}}

{{4, 3}, {8, 6}}
```