# Delete duplicates in a set of Data?

Tags: list-manipulation, version-9

If

```
n=10;

Union[Flatten[Table[If[PrimeQ[p] == True && p + q == 2 n, {p, q}, {}], {p, 3, 
2 n}, {q, 1, 2 n - p}], 1]]
```

which its output is

```
{{}, {3, 17}, {5, 15}, {7, 13}, {11, 9}, {13, 7}, {17, 3}, {19, 1}}
```

I like to have

```
{{}, {3, 17}, {5, 15}, {7, 13}, {11, 9}, {19, 1}}
```

or

```
{{3, 17}, {5, 15}, {7, 13}, {11, 9}, {19, 1}}
```

as a result, i.e., since `{3,17}` is the same as `{17,3}`, we only need one of them.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "as output" mean? Does it mean `StringTake[ToString@{0, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {{6}}}, {2, -2}]`?

Comment: `0,{1,2},{3,4,5},{{6}}` is not a valid Mathematica expression. Do you want it `Print`ed? If so `StringTake[ToString[{0, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {{6}}}], {2, -2}]`

Comment: @Alan,, thanks for your comment, I gave another example.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer,  thanks for your comment, I gave another example.

Comment: How is the second example related to the first?  It appears to be a completely different question.

Comment: @jjc385, I updated the question.

Comment: `With[{n = 10}, DeleteDuplicatesBy[Flatten[Table[If[PrimeQ[p] && p + q == 2 n, {p, q}, Nothing], {p, 3, 2 n}, {q, 2 n - p}], 1], Sort]]`

Comment: @J.M., `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is not defined in Mathematica 9. :(

Comment: Duplicate question with some good comprehensive answers https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140571/delete-redundant-x-y-pairs

Answer (score 6):

Starting with

```
list = {{}, {3, 17}, {5, 15}, {7, 13}, {11, 9}, {13, 7}, {17, 3}, {19, 1}}
```

You can remove reordered sublists with

```
noDuplicates = DeleteDuplicatesBy[ list, Sort ]
```

> ```
> {{}, {3, 17}, {5, 15}, {7, 13}, {11, 9}, {19, 1}}
> ```

Then you can remove empty sublists with

```
noEmpties = DeleteCases[ noDuplicates, {} ]
```

> ```
> {{3, 17}, {5, 15}, {7, 13}, {11, 9}, {19, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is a small problem, My Mathematica version is 9, and `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is not defined.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[list, Equal @@ Sort /@ {##} &]` in older versions.  Id also suggest more simply `DeleteDuplicates[Sort/@list]`  will be faster if you don't mind having everything sorted in the result.

Comment: @george2079, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 2):

```
n=10;
Flatten[DeleteDuplicates[Table[If[PrimeQ[p] && p + q == 2 n, Sort[{p, q}], Nothing], {p, 3, 
2 n}, {q, 1, 2 n - p}]], 1]
```

> {{3, 17}, {5, 15}, {7, 13}, {9, 11}, {1, 19}}

**Update**

Much faster if the duplicates and empty lists are avoided from the get go.

```
n = 10; 
Cases[IntegerPartitions[2 n, {2}], ls : {___, _?PrimeQ, ___} :> 
Switch[ls, {1 | 2, Except[_?PrimeQ]} | {Except[_?PrimeQ], 1 | 2}, Nothing, _, ls]]
```

> {{19, 1}, {17, 3}, {15, 5}, {13, 7}, {11, 9}}

Comparison:

```
n = 1000;

l1 = Flatten[
DeleteDuplicates[
 Table[If[PrimeQ[p] && p + q == 2 n, Sort[{p, q}], Nothing], {p, 
   3, 2 n}, {q, 1, 2 n - p}]], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming

l2 = Cases[IntegerPartitions[2 n, {2}], 
ls : {___, _?PrimeQ, ___} :> 
 Switch[ls, {1 | 2, Except[_?PrimeQ]} | {Except[_?PrimeQ], 1 | 2},
   Nothing, _, ls]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Equal @@ (Length /@ {l1, l2}) && Complement[Sort /@ l1, Sort /@ l2] == {}
```

> {1.58086, Null}
>
> {0.004746, Null}
>
> True