# Again the For loops

Tags: list-manipulation

I failed to use `DeleteCases` to eliminate from a `list` of pairs when they are the same {a,b} {a,b} or {a,b} {b,a}. To test finally I wrote the procedure using `For` `For` and `If` and `Reap` `Saw` to identify the elements that i had to delete ... but I can not found the way this is what I did including the sample generator

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Remove["Global`*"]

ldp = Range[11, 99];

ldpp = RandomChoice[ldp, 200];

ldppp = Partition[ldpp, 2, 1, -1];

For[i = 1, i < Length[ldppp], i++,
    For[j = i + 1, j <= Length[ldppp], j++,
        If[Or[ldppp[[i]] == ldppp[[j]], 
    ldppp[[i]] == Reverse[ldppp[[j]]]], Print[ldppp[[i]], ldppp[[j]]]]
        ]
    ]

Reap[
 For[i = 1, i < Length[ldppp], i++,
    For[j = i + 1, j <= Length[ldppp], j++,
        If[Or[ldppp[[i]] == ldppp[[j]], 
     ldppp[[i]] == Reverse[ldppp[[j]]]], 
    Sow[{ldppp[[i]], ldppp[[j]]}]]]
        ]
    ]
```

I would appreciate some trick to move to functional style

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[ldppp, Sort]`?

Comment: I thought must be simple but    stay focused en DeleteCases...  feel like the skier who bumps in the only tree in the track!   thanks @Kuba

Comment: No worries. p.s. just leaving another closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140571/5478

Comment: `DeleteCases[{{a,b},{a,c},{b,a}}, {a,b}|{b,a}]` gives you `{a,c}` if that helps